# kernel can't detect CPU

Tags: 14.04, kernel, cpu

I am working on vmware with 2 CPUs with ubuntu 14.04 TLS, i installed the low latency kernel 3.19.0-61. But The CPUs are unknow fot this kernel:

```
~$ cpufreq-info

cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

Please, How can i fix this problem.

Comment: I do not think that vmware sees  the actual CPU.

Comment: The messages just mean you do not have any CPU frequency scaling driver. It doesn't mean the kernel can not detect the CPU.

Comment: OK thank you, and how can i enable frequency scaling.

Comment: In a VM, I don't know. I would expect CPU frequency scaling to handled by the host computer on the real physical CPUs, not the guest VM's VCPUs.